# Call external web service in JS library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to build a chat widget using JS library of a chat simulator and tried to use it with web service one of the questions as following:

1. Call the external web service when the user reach on the last dummy chat message, which is 'type your concern'
2. Pass the collected data to the web service API
3. Reply with the real chat message from external web service after the last dummy chat message

I can't get the response data fetch from/to the web service when the user reached to 'Type your concern', what is currently happening is the chatbox reload itself when reached to 'Type your concern' and everything was cleared.

Please help me.

JS:

```
var chatInfo = {chatInfo: [...]};

        alert ('aaa');
        function getinfo(convState, ready) {
            alert ('bbb');
            var chatMsg = $('#chatConcern').val();
                if(chatMsg>=0) {
                    alert ('ccc');
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: 'https://example.webservice/',
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        data: JSON.stringify(chatInfo),
                        success: function (response) {
                            console.log("Thanks!");
                        },
                        error: function (response) { alert(response.d); }

                    });
                } else {
                    convState.current.next = false;
                }
        }

        jQuery(function($){
            var count = 0;
            var original = false;
            var convForm = $('#chat').convform({
                eventList:{
                    onInputSubmit: function(convState, ready) {
                        console.log('input is being submitted...');
                //here you send the response to your API, get the results and build the next question
                //when ready, call 'ready' callback (passed as the second parameter)
                if(convState.current.answer.value ==='end') {
                    convState.current.next = original;
                    //emulating random response time (100-600ms)
                    setTimeout(ready, Math.random()*500+100);
                } else {

                    setTimeout(ready, Math.random()*500+100);
                }
                count++;

                /* function getinfo(stateWrapper, ready) {
                    window.open("https://google.com");
                    ready();
                } */
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

HTML:

```
<section id="demo">
        <div class="vertical-align">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-offset-0">
                        <div class="card no-border">
                            <div id="chat">
                                <form action="" method="GET" class="hidden">
                                    <select data-conv-question="Hello! This is an example use of the plugin to dynamically generate questions (like using an API). This is the only question that was written on the initial HTML. To end the loop, select END." name="first-question">
                                        <option value="understood">Understood</option>
                                        <option value="okay">Okay, captain!</option>
                                    </select>

                                    <div data-conv-case="understood">
                                        <input type="text" name="fullName" data-conv-question="What is your full name?">
                                        <input type="email" data-pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$" name="email" data-conv-question="What is your e-mail address?">
                                        <input type="concern" name="cs" data-conv-question="Type your concern">
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @charlietfl, sorry. the one with number list

Comment: Those aren't questions. They outline your goal but not code related problems related to achieving that goal. Take a few minutes to read through [ask]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, this appears to be using a plugin or library, it's not clear. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @charlietfl, I've updated the post

Comment: @Twisty, please see the updated post

Comment: @OleDevL this still does not show what you have tried or all the details. Where is `ready` defined for the following: `setTimeout(ready, Math.random()*500+100);`

Comment: @OleDevL where is `convState` defined?